# parse data to array from an std object

Tags: php, json, parsing, mashape

ive tried to get some data from mashape and then called it onto raw_body:

```
$data = $response -> raw_body;
```

i get this result:

```
{ "internalName": "jokb93", "dataVersion": 0, "acctId": 22059705, "name": "jokb93", "profileIconId": 31, "revisionDate": "Sep 14, 2013 3:36:46 PM", "revisionId": 0, "summonerId": 19355532, "summonerLevel": 30 }
```

then i try parsing it into seperate arrays for php to handle:

```
var json = '<? echo $data ?>',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.internalName);
```

([Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript))

but it seems to end out blank?

thx for ur time hope u can figure this out :-D

Comment: `var json = '<? $data ?>',` -- I don't think is what you need. Try echoing it instead. `<?php echo $data; ?>` or use the shorthand syntax: `<?=$data?>`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you're going with this, but bear in mind that all PHP is executed *before* the page is sent to the browser, and all JS *after* it is sent. The code you've written is fine, as it is giving the result of PHP to JS; but if you were thinking you could then give the result of the JS straight back to PHP, you will be disappointed.

Comment: sry there should have been an echo in there... but where im going right now:
i want the internal name to be parsed to something handable for a server... probly the wrong approach then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i got it now...

here is the api i call to:

```
    $response = Unirest::get(
  "https://community-league-of-legends.p.mashape.com/api/v1.0/".$server."/summoner/getSummonerByName/".$sumname."",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "tLOVnMy2q8uGSEQHkG2kLquS1sgLfkso"
  ));
```

and to get the print of waht i want i do like this:

```
      $accid = $response->body->acctId;

  $intname = $response->body->internalName;

  echo $accid;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $intname;
```

this would work for anyone who needs to parse something down from their stdobject(if from mashape).

thx for the guidance guys.. :-D have a nice night... time to sleep now::

btw it echos this out then

```
22059705
jokb93
```

(depending on the values you put in)